Converting GeoPandas points to polygons and retaining column information
I have a geodata frame that looks something like this:



Index
Side
UniqueID
GroupName
geometry




0
Blue
S1A1B1-D1
Group1
POINT(##.#####, ##.#####)


1
Blue
S1A2B1-D1
Group2
POINT(##.#####, ##.#####)


2
Blue
S1A1B2-D1
Group1
POINT(##.#####, ##.#####)


3
Blue
S1A1B1-D2
Group2
POINT(##.#####, ##.#####)


4
Blue
S3A1B1-D1
Group1
POINT(##.#####, ##.#####)


...







I want to create polygons based off the groupname, but retain my ability to use/access/see the groupname column?
I tried:
res = gdf.dissolve("GroupName").convex_hull

Which produced a series of the unique polygons. But I can't really do anything with them? They plot correctly, so that's good. I can see the name on the row
geometry
Group1   POLYGON((##.###### ##.#######, ##.##### ##.#####)...)
Group2   POLYGON((##.###### ##.#######, ##.##### ##.#####)...)

I need to be able to filter which ones are being displayed, by name (ideally side as well, but I can handle that so long as I can at least get to the name), on a dash mapbox.
But I can't seem to access the groupname part of the output?
list(res.select_dtypes('geometry'))[0]

was suggested elsewhere but just spits out 0

You need to turn your res GeoSeries object into a GeoDataFrame and convert the series index back to a column.
In one line
res = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf.dissolve("GroupName").convex_hull).reset_index()

Explanation
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("points.shp")
res = gdf.dissolve("GroupName").convex_hull

print(type(res))
# geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries

## Make it a GDF
res = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf.dissolve("GroupName").convex_hull)

## Show GroupName is actually the index 
print(res.index)
# Index(['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'], dtype='object', name='GroupName')

# Turn index back into column
res = res.reset_index()

print(gdf.head())
#    id GroupName  geometry
# 0   1    Group1  POINT (xxxx yyyy)

print(res.head())
#   GroupName                                                  0
# 0    Group1  POLYGON ((xxxx yyyy, xxxx yyyy, ...

